# Devise expire notification on email confirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, devise-confirmable

I have included confirmation module in devise gem and it working fine but i need to alert the user with some flash message on after 2 days(based on the devise config) for unconfirmed emails on login.

```
config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = 2.days
```

how to add a button to resend mail for confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a button which links to a controller action, and create a route for it like `resend_email_path(user)`. Inside the controller action you need to include:

```
  def resend_email
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    user.send_confirmation_instructions
  end
```

For more information on this method see:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/9f37b6eff7b4f9b0441be5a687b3091db82befc4/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb#L110-L117

Once you get it working normally you could do it ajaxy with `remote: true`

**To add the flash  message**, put this in in the controller action where your uncomfirmed user is:

```
if current_user.confirmation_period_expired?
  flash[:error] = "Confirmation Time Expired. #{link_to 'Resend email', resend_email_path(user)}".html_safe
end
```

See: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/9f37b6eff7b4f9b0441be5a687b3091db82befc4/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb#L218-L220

Comment: thanks Abram, but how to add the flash alert on the date of expiry